# Layover with duty-free bags

Tags: usa, duty-free

I have never purchased anything duty-free before but I'm planning to before my flight to the US (where I'm a citizen).

However, I'm leaving the airport for a hotel. I don't normally check a bag. What can I expect with my duty-free alcohol purchase? Can I bring it back in the duty-free bag and keep it on my carry on for my second, domestic leg?

Or should I plan on checking a bag for the domestic leg with the alcohol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to bring liquids onto a second flight. Plan on packing your purchases in a bag and check it in.